# If $M,N$ are structures of some first order language , $N$ is finite and $h: N \to M$ is an elementary embedding, then is $h$ an isomorphism?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $L$ be a first order language, let $M,N$ be $L$-structures such that $N$ is finite. Let $h: N \to M$ be an elementary embedding i.e. for every $L$-formula  $\psi[x_1,...,x_n]$ , we have $N \vDash \psi[a_1,...,a_n] \Leftrightarrow M\vDash \psi [h(a_1),...,h(a_n)],\forall a_1,...,a_n \in N$.

Then is it true that $h: N \to M$ is an isomorphism of $L$-structures ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can formalize a first-order formula which asserts a structure has $|N|$ elements. $N$ satisfies this formula, hence $M$ also does. Since $h$ is one-to-one, $h$ is bijective. Now we get $h$ is an isomorphism, by elementarility.